# document.head v. document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the difference between using `document.head` and using `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`? Tests I ran showed that they both take about a millisecond.

I have also seen

```
document.head||document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

which would have led me to believe that `document.head` is faster and the other is more more compatible, <strike>except that the tests I did disproved this.</strike>

And if one is more compatible, why use the other as well?

**Update:** My tests were wrong, as some have pointed out.

Comment: You can also do `document.querySelector("head")`. It's just a matter of choice.

Comment: It pretty much can't become any faster than having a direct reference. So `document.head` should be faster by a magnitude, see http://jsperf.com/document-head-vs-getelementsbytagname

Comment: 2019 update: please stop adding unnecessary `|| document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`, IE8 is *long* dead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the `||` operator like that is a form of feature detection. When used, if the first value is undefined it sends back the latter value.

So for

```
document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

the reason is that if `document.head` is not supported at least the right value is returned.

As for your speed test, a millisecond is a long time. I doubt it really took that long. In fact, I made a ***[`jsPerf`](http://jsperf.com/document-head-versus-bytagname)*** for this. It shows that the `getElementsByTagName` function is roughly 80% slower.

Comment: Agree that they don't take the same time, `getElementsByTagName` gets slower as the DOM size increases. And `1ms` is a sign that it was poorly measured

Comment: @Sortofabeginner `console.time()` is good enough for this purpose, but you'd have to measure more than once to get decent accuracy

Comment: `document.querySelector` is even [slower](http://jsperf.com/document-head-versus-bytagname/2)...

Comment: Shouldn't document.documentElement be included?

Answer (score 5):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.head), `document.head` only gained support in IE 9, so using the other method as a fallback protects you from browser incompatibilities

Comment: But if `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` is more compatible, why use `document.head` at all?

Comment: @Sortofabeginner Because it's shorter, and easier to read. There are multiple ways to query the DOM. In some cases, the *other way* may become deprecated. I don't suspect that will happen in this case though.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a convenience matter than a performance one (though `document.head` should have a negligible benefit). Use which ever you like, or, use one as a fallback to the other (as your example code does). Having the fallback is wise, since `document.head` is not support in IE 6-8.

It's not likely that `getElementsByTagName` will soon be deprecated, so this isn't a great example of when it's good to provide a fallback. You could safely use the more verbose route on its own and enjoy support on into the future.

Better examples of these types of things would be events, and how they're passed around in modern browsers, compared to older browsers. It is not uncommon to see something like this:

```
function callback (event) {
    var id = (event || window.event).target.id;
}
```

In this case though, the `window.event` portion is necessary for legacy support. If the `event` object is `undefined`, we assume the event is a member on the `window` object. As browsers mature, `window.event` ceases to be *a thing*, and these tests unanimously return `event.target.id` instead.

Again, your case is a bit different as `getElementsByTagName` will likely never be deprecated or vanish as `window.event` did.

Comment: I don't think a ~83% performance penalty is *just* a matter of convenience. http://jsperf.com/document-head-vs-getelementsbytagname

Comment: @jAndy ~83% on this scale is negligible. This is not the type of preoptimization web developers need to be worrying about, generally speaking.

Comment: I disagree. I'd expect to query for DOM elements as fast as anyhow possible, since this kind of operation might happen thousands of times.

Comment: @jAndy If your page is querying for the `head` element *thousands of times*, you have no business being in this industry ;) I think we can both agree that cached references to DOM nodes is better than repeatedly looking them up. But the speed different for getting the `head` element is negligible.

Comment: well, I was talking about DOM queries, but I guess you just wanna tease here. I just disagree that the performance penalty of accessing a property + executing a function + accessing the resulting HTMLCollection is neglible in comparison to a direct reference. This spreads a very wrong message.

Comment: @jAndy We're talking about querying for the `head` element; not *elements in general*. Clearly cached references are quicker than making repeated trips to the DOM. Please don't mistake my position here, I'm on your side 99% of the time.

Comment: I know, but still, there are other shortcuts like `document.body`, `document.images`, `document.links` etc. which are about the same topic. I wouldn't dare to recommend to use `getElementsByTagName()`, I'd always state to use those references, not just for convenience, every day all day.

Comment: @jAndy I would agree that `document.images` is better than crawling the DOM for *multiple tags*. But that's apples and oranges; we're talking about `document.head`, which craws the DOM (very briefly since it's at the top) for one element.

Comment: well, I guess we look at things differently, but fair enough.

Comment: @jAndy Not too much differently; again, multiple trips, or single trips for multiple elements, always take the most performant route. In this case, `document.head` is better, but isn't more appealing because of a major performance boost (though it technically provides a boost).

Answer (score 1):

Just convenience because you are only supposed to have one per page. Just like there is a direct shortcut to `document.body`, although `document.body` is standard and you wouldn't need the fallback.

```
document.body || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

I wouldn't use `document.head` unless you only support IE9+. Until then, I would stick to `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`

If you want a version that you don't have to change as time goes by, you can do the following at the top of your script

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

That way you can just change that one place when you drop support for IE8 (or may even leave it there since it doesn't hurt, but it will be dead code). The above code would also make sure you only query the DOM once

Comment: You put body instead of head.

Comment: You only fixed it in one location - there are several other instances.

Comment: @sortofabeginner the first one is intentional to show the same pattern can be used for document.body

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder if `document.head||(document.head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);`wouldn`t be slightly faster?

Comment: @Sortofabeginner faster than what? Why would that be any faster than `document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];` if you follow my suggestion it only happens once anyway, I think you're splitting hairs, if you have a real performance question, ask a new one